# построение html таблиц

Tags: html, css

как сделать такую таблицу? кто может объяснить работу тегов tr и td и атрибутов: rowspan и colspan.Как я могу сделать такую таблицу? Что нужно считать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зря вы исправили вопрос так, чтобы он был на английском. Это русскоязычный сайт. Верните все как было, пока вопрос не закрыли.

Comment: По-моему, легче всего использовать визуальный генератор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` создает горизонтальную строку.
`td` разделяет ее на колонки.

`colspan=n` объединяет n колонок.
`rowspan=m` объединяет m строк.

> что считать, какой алгоритм действий нужно соблюдать?

Посчитайте максимальное количество строк в одной колонке - это количество `tr`'ов. После этого посчитайте максимальное количество  колонок в одной строке. Это будет количество `td`'ов, которые нужно поместить в каждый из `tr`'ов. Дальше некоторым строкам и колонкам, которые занимают сразу несколько строк или колонок добавляете `rowspan` или `colspan` соответственно, с числом, равным количеству строк или колонок, которые объединены.

Данный алгоритм вам подойдет в том случае, если вас не особо интересует ширина пустых колонок. Если это важно, то придется либо использовать CSS для стилизации, либо использовать другой алгоритм.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали, colspan - объединяет ячейки по горизонтали (колонки), rowspan - по вертикали (строки). Разберем на предложенном Вами примере. Берем первую ячейку, смотрим, подсчитываем - на её высоте сколько различных строк помещается - получается, что 4. пишем: `<td rowspan=4>`. Сколько столбцов? Один - можно написать, конечно, `colspan=1`, но это некрасиво и мне лень, поэтому ничего не будем дописывать. Следующая ячейка в строчке - аналогично, `<td rowspan=4>`. Далее еще круче - она занимает в строчку 3 и в столбик 2, записываем `<td rowspan=2 colspan=3`. Последняя - `<td colspan=3>`.

Переходим ко второй строчке. Но начинаем не с самой левой ячейки - её мы уже упомянули, проходя предыдущую строчку. Но что остается тогда? Да только одна ячейка, все остальные мы "прошли" на предыдущей строке. Эта ячейка занимает 3 в ряд: `<td colspan=3>`.

Аналогично дальше.

А вот схема, которая требовалась в вопросе (стиль просто какой-то рандомный, чтобы видно было хотя бы че-то)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup width="80"/>
  <colgroup width="100"/>
  <colgroup width="90"/>
  <colgroup width="40"/>
  <colgroup width="110"/>
  <colgroup width="100"/>
  <colgroup width="90"/>
  <colgroup width="130"/>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=4></td>
    <td rowspan=4></td>
    <td colspan=3 rowspan=2></td>
    <td colspan=3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=2></td>
  <td rowspan=2></td>
  <td rowspan=2></td>
  <td colspan=2></td>
  <td rowspan=2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=5></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td rowspan=5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=2></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=4></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Кстати, схема не полностью совпадает с требуемой.

Comment: @Alex78191, а теперь?

Comment: Сейчас идеально.

Comment: не понимаю, как вы узнали, сколько нужно ставитьв атрибуте colspan?

Comment: @sekeke6, [вот так](https://i.imgur.com/19Ui4r8.png), посмотрел, что в ширину максимум верхняя ячейка занимает 3 - поэтому и написал `colspan=3`. Я не знаю как по-другому объяснить). Вы попробуйте сами сделать какую-нибудь табличку и посмотреть что происходит, когда меняешь эти параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Пример с применением только базовых атрибутов табличек:

```html
<table width=100% border=5>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=4> 1 </td>
    <td rowspan=4> 2 </td>
    <td colspan=3 rowspan=2> 3 </td>
    <td colspan=3> 4 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan=3> 5 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2> 6 </td>
    <td rowspan=2> 7 </td>
    <td rowspan=2> 8 </td>
    <td colspan=2> 9 </td>
    <td rowspan=2> 10 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> 11 </td>
    <td> 12 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5> 13 </td>
    <td> 14 </td>
    <td> 15 </td>
    <td> 16 </td>
    <td> 17 </td>
    <td> 18 </td>
    <td> 19 </td>
    <td rowspan=5> 20 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2> 21 </td>
    <td> 22 </td>
    <td> 23 </td>
    <td> 24 </td>
    <td> 25 </td>
    <td> 26 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> 27 </td>
    <td> 28 </td>
    <td> 29 </td>
    <td> 30 </td>
    <td> 31 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> 32 </td>
    <td> 33 </td>
    <td> 34 </td>
    <td> 35 </td>
    <td> 36 </td>
    <td> 37 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan=4> 38 </td>
    <td> 39 </td>
    <td> 40 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```